# java.rmi.ConnectIOException & java.net.SocketException: Socket operation on nonsocket: connect

Tags: java, exception, rmi, dht

I'm an italian guy, so sorry for my BAD english.

I'm writing a RMI program in Java, and this is the section of the node's code to connect to the RMI server:

```
try
        {//trying to connect to the Server
        Remote RemoteObject;
        BootstrapServer_Interface serverObject;
        Registry r = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(10001);
        RemoteObject = r.lookup("BOOTSTRAP-SERVER");//THIS IS LINE 52
        serverObject = (BootstrapServer_Interface)RemoteObject;
        //I get an ip as Server's answerw
        System.out.println("Il nodo "+Thread.currentThread()+" si mette in attesa");
        String ipBN = serverObject.start_join_node(fakeip);
        if(ipBN.equals("-1"))
            {System.out.println("Creazione del nodo "+Thread.currentThread()+" fallito");
            return;
            }
```

However, **sometimes**, the program get this exception:

```
java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: 131.114.43.246; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketException: Socket operation on nonsocket: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at StorageNode.run(StorageNode.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket operation on nonsocket: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    ... 9 more
```

And this the client's code to connect to the RMI server:

```
try
            {//scelgo casualmente un dato da cercare        
            //genero il mio indirizzo ip
            fakeip = String.valueOf((int) (Math.random() * 256)) + "."
                    + String.valueOf((int) (Math.random() * 256)) + "."
                    + String.valueOf((int) (Math.random() * 256)) + "."
                    + String.valueOf((int) (Math.random() * 256));
            //creo una Socket UDP con cui contattare il Nodo di Bootstrap
            UDPServiceSocket = scanner.UDPSocket();
            if(UDPServiceSocket==null)
                {System.out.println("Tentativo di creazione socket UDP fallito...");
                *return;}
            int UDPport = UDPServiceSocket.getLocalPort();
            fakeip=fakeip+" UDPport="+UDPport;
            //mi connetto al server tramite RMI
            Remote RemoteObject;
            Registry r = LocateRegistry.getRegistry(10001);
            RemoteObject = r.lookup("BOOTSTRAP-SERVER");//THIS IS LINE 48
            serverObject = (BootstrapServer_Interface)RemoteObject;
            //Ottengo l'ip del Bootstrap Node a cui connettermi
            System.out.println("Il client "+Thread.currentThread()+" si mette in attesa.");         
            ipBN = serverObject.client_search();
            }
```

And the exception in this case **(that not necessarily happen together with the node exception that I Posted above)**

```
java.rmi.ConnectIOException: Exception creating connection to: 131.114.43.246; nested exception is: 
    java.net.SocketException: Socket operation on nonsocket: connect
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.lookup(Unknown Source)
    at Client.run(Client.java:48)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Socket operation on nonsocket: connect
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.Socket.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(Unknown Source)
```

I can't find any reason that cause this exception.

I'm sorry for the less code that I posted before, but it's a little part of a big project, so I cannot past all the code :D

However, if you need it, I can give you some informations about it:

1. This is a DHT project, and this is the node code while he's trying
       to contact the Bootstrap Server (indeed, a RMI Server).
2. The RMI server methods could be called by many nodes (the code above) and/or
       many client at the same time.
3. The server methods called by nodes
       and/or clients are created to manage a Monitor installed on the
       Server.
4. Through this monitor, the nodes and clients modifies an Hash
       Table following the model of "writers and readers" (mutual exclusion
       ecc.).

Thanks a lot to everyone that will help me with this issue, and sorry again for my bad english!

Comment: What JVM version are you using? I saw this around 1.4.x times, never since.

Comment: by java -version : 1.6.0_35